# Сериализация IEnumerable в котором ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть веб-приложение в котором я отображаются некоторые данные, я хочу с бд выгрузить данные в xml.

Вот модель

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public IFormFile UploadedFile { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeTasksDTO> EmployeeTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Что бы выгрузить в xml я сначала считываю все данные в `IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO>` далее с помощь метода конвертирую `IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO>` в `DataTable`

```
protected DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        Type type = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();

        foreach(PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
        property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach(T item in collection)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow.BeginEdit();
            foreach(PropertyInfo property in propertyInfos)
            {
                dataRow[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataRow.EndEdit();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        dataTable.TableName = $"{type.Name}_details";
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Так как таких списков 3, я сделал этот метод дженерик
один список в котором `IEnumerable == null` выгружается в XML без проблем
Но остальные с ошибкой

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[BLayer.DTO.EmployeeTasksDTO, BLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' does not implement IXmlSerializable interface therefore can not proceed with serialization.
```

Как мне исправить это?

```
protected void WriteAndSaveXMLFile(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(AppSetting.SetXMLFilesPath(), dataTable.TableName);

        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, null))
        {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            dataTable.WriteXml(writer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Совершенно непонятно. У вас проблема с xml-сериализацией, но её код не показан.

Comment: При чём тут метка asp.net core? Разве код как-то связан с этой технологией? Зато нет метки языка программирования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хммм, интересно, на каком языке еще можно писать на asp.net-core

Comment: На любом языке под платформу .NET (а их десятки), если не брать в расчёт представления. / Метка языка нужна для того, чтобы вопрос увидели те, кто подписан на эту метку. / Я ещё раз повторю: ваш вопрос никак не связан с asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так с помощью `DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type)` теперь все окей

```
public MemoryStream Export(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            Type type = collection.GetType();
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type);

            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, null))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(writer, item);
                }
            }

            return stream;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
WriteAndSaveXMLFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, string filePath)
{    
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer();

    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, entities);
    }
}
```

Написал без возможности проверить, так что, возможно, придется отладить.